# Starting an app from another app

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I have two problems:

1. I need to start an app from another app.
2. I need to make two certain image links do just one action each (right now, both of them do both action).

Details for no. 1: i've directly called `Process.Start("D:\\proba/ControlsBasics-WPF.appref-ms");` 
What do I do when I move the app or instal it on a different computer and the respective user does not have that pathway? I want to make a connection between two apps.

Details for no.2: right now, I have two image links (pic2) that open both a main window and an article . I need to make one of them open the main window and the other one open the article. I've done a printscreen so that you can see the codelines for the image links.

This is a very important problem for me and I hope I was clear enough.
Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3fVi.jpg

I've also added the code so that you can see it better:

```
<List x:TypeArguments="mskbm:ExperienceOptionModel" xmlns="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:mskbm="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.InteractionGallery.Models;assembly=InteractionGallery-WPF" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <mskbm:ExperienceOptionModel 
        Name="VIDEO" 
        ImageUri="pack://application:,,,/Content/HomeScreen/01.png"
        OverlayImageUri="pack://application:,,,/Content/HomeScreen/play-overlay.png"
        NavigableContextName="Video" 
        NavigableContextParameter="Content/Videos/K4W.wmv" />
    <mskbm:ExperienceOptionModel 
        Name="VIDEO" 
        ImageUri="pack://application:,,,/Content/HomeScreen/02.png"
        OverlayImageUri="pack://application:,,,/Content/HomeScreen/play-overlay.png"
        NavigableContextName="Video" 
        NavigableContextParameter="Content/Videos/K4W_NISSAN.wmv" />
    <mskbm:ExperienceOptionModel 
        Name="MAPPA PUNTI VENDITA" 
        ImageUri="pack://application:,,,/Content/img/03.png"
        NavigableContextName="PannableContent" 
        NavigableContextParameter="pack://application:,,,/Content/PannableContentScreen/WorldMap.xaml" />
    <mskbm:ExperienceOptionModel 
        Name="TUTORIAL KINECT" 
        ImageUri="pack://application:,,,/Content/img/05.png" 
        NavigableContextName="Article" 
        NavigableContextParameter="pack://application:,,,/Content/ArticleScreen/Article2.xaml" />
    <mskbm:ExperienceOptionModel 
       Name="CATALOGO INTERATTIVO" 
        ImageUri="pack://application:,,,/Content/img/01.png" 
        NavigableContextName="Article" 
        NavigableContextParameter="pack://application:,,,/Content/ArticleScreen/Article2.xaml" />
    <mskbm:ExperienceOptionModel 
        Name="INFO E CONTANTI" 
        ImageUri="pack://application:,,,/Content/img/06.png" 
        NavigableContextName="Article" 
        NavigableContextParameter="pack://application:,,,/Content/ArticleScreen/Article2.xaml" />
</List>
```

Comment: 1. You need to provide a way for the user to define the path or you need to search for the other application yourself and save the path. 2. Do you really expect people to be able to read your code from an image?

Comment: When you say the application may be installed on a different computer, do you intend for it to run on the other computer (the user launches it from your Kinect UI, but it runs on the other box)? If so, do you need to know anything about the application after it launches (for example, do you need to know when it stops running)?

Comment: I have the setup for the other app, but the problem is that when I move the app on a different computer, it doesn't find the path to the executable file. As you can see, the pathway is "D:\\proba/ControlsBasics-WPF.appref-ms"  . How can i rewrite it so that the app opens even if the user does not have that pathway.